# How to separate each category by tbody tag inside the same table

Tags: php, html, loops, html-table

I have this code which is intended to build a table where each building would create a new table with a caption tag containing the building name and also grouping each person and computer into their respective sector, using a tbody that also has a tr with its name before each group.
Something like:

```
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <caption>Building 1</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="title"><td>Sector1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 3</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="title"><td>Sector2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 3</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
            <caption>Building 2</caption>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="title"><td>Sector1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 2</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Person 3</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I am starting (stuck) with this:

```
        if ($STH->fetch() > 0):
            $sector;
            $building;
            $tbodyf = "<tbody><tr class='primary'><th colspan='2'>Building: %s</th></tr>\n";
            $tbodytitle = "\n<tr class='info'>\n<td colspan='2'><b>Sector: %s</b></td>\n</tr>\n";
            $tbodytr = "<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>\n";


            while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {

                if ($row->building !== $building) {
                    $building = $row->building;
                    printf($tbodyf, $building);
                }

                if ($row->sector !== $sector) {
                    $sector = $row->sector;
                    printf($tbodytitle, $sector);
                }
                printf($tbodytr, $row->person, $row->hostname);
            }
        else:
            echo '<h3>Nothing to see!</h3>';
        endif;
```

Comment: Stuck? Tell us what the problem is.

Comment: Hi. This code generates table with almost the correct structure. It makes the first tr of a group of items the title (building name) and the second the subtitle (sector name) but doesn't wrap them inside a tbody. I was trying to do it with a single table but making each building a new tbody containing a title (caption) and subtitle (first tr), but I think separating buildings by table would be better.

Comment: Probably because you never end the <tbody>s with </tbody>s.

Comment: Is not there because I don't now the proper place to echo it.

Comment: A simple way would be to set a flag before the while; for example $first = true. Then, when you find a new building, check if $first is true. If so, set it false, otherwise echo the </tbody> before tbodyf.